# Elasticsearch - Query string w/ time range

Tags: elasticsearch

essentially I want to find documents where "variable ABC contains 'apple' and only count documents from 1 day ago". For context, this is the request body of a curl request.

This will return all documents where ABC is 'apple':

```
 '{ 
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "apple",
             "default_field": "ABC"
            }
        }
    }'
```

This unfortunately does not work:

```
'{ 
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "apple",
             "default_field": "ABC"
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "range": {"nest.nest1.nest2.timestamps.start": {"gte": "now-1d"}}
            }
        }
    }'
```

Sample document I want to find, highly abbreviated, and thanks for helping:

```
    {
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "indexabc",
        "_id": "IDabc",
        "_score": "15"
        "_source": {
             "ABC": "applebottom",
             "nest": {
                 "nest1": {
                    "nest2": {
                        "timestamps": {
                            "start": "2022-09-01T08:00:10+00:00",
                            "send": "2022-09-01T08:16:20+00:00"
                        }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     ]
```

Comment: will your search term always at start or it can be anywhere in text ex . will you only search for apple or also bot in applebottom

Comment: @jaspreetchahal If I'm understanding you, I want to find all documents where variable 'ABC' contains 'apple' so it wouldn't matter it had text before or after the word

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way:

```
{
  "query": {
   "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "apple",
          "default_field": "ABC"
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter": [
      {
        "range": {
          "nest.nest1.nest2.timestamps.start": {
            "gte": "now-1d"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, returned is "[must] query malformed". I tried containing the "must" and "filter" within "bool" however I get 0 hits if I run the request as such.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this

**1. Wildcard**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*apple*", --> wildcard
            "default_field": "ABC"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "nest.nest1.nest2.timestamps.start": {
              "gte": "now-1y"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

wildcards are slow. If you are facing performance issues, then there are other ways to resolve this.

**2. [Prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)**

if your search text is at start of word, you can use a simple prefix query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "ABC": "apple"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "nest.nest1.nest2.timestamps.start": {
              "gte": "now-1y"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**3. [NGrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)**

```
PUT index24
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 5,
          "max_gram": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ABC": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
} 


GET index24/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "ABC",
            "query": "apple"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "nest.nest1.nest2.timestamps.start": {
              "gte": "now-1y"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

for "applebottom" following tokens will be generated
["apple","ppleb","plebo","lebot","ebott","bottom"]. You can adjust tokens generated using "min_gram": 5 and "max_gram": 5.

Ngrams will let you search anywhere between a text and give better search performance as tokens are created at index time. It will give better search performance at expense of increase in index size